# Efficient way to store lots of strings in android app

Tags: android

In my app, I have a listview which contains hundreds or rows. It is a custom listview with two textviews (title & description).

What I have currently done is that I have two string arrays in strings.xml. One that stores all the headings for the listview and other array that stores all the descriptions for the lsitview. When the listview is created, I populate the listviews with the heading and the description from each of the string arrays.

The problem is that it is getting difficult to manage so many strings.

It would be great if anyone can suggest any other efficient way to achieve this.

The reason I am using strings is that we have very similar other projects to do further, where  even some non-programmer can replace the string array values for us. That is why we dont use sqlite.

```
<string-array name="Headings">
    <item>Heading1</item>
    <item>Heading2</item>
    .
    .
</string-array>

<string-array name="Desc">
    <item>Desc1</item>
    <item>Desc2</item>
    .
    .
</string-array>



.java file

List<RowItem> rowItems= new ArrayList<RowItem>();

titles=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Headings);
descriptions=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Desc);

for (int j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {
  RowItem item = new RowItem(titles[j], descriptions[j]);
  rowItems.add(item);
}


ListView lv=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item,rowItems);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
    Context context;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<RowItem> items) {
      super(context, resourceId, items);
      this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        textView1.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        textView2.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
        return rowView;
    }
}


public class RowItem {
    private String title;
    private String desc;

    public RowItem(String title, String desc) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + "\n" + desc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code , so we can understand well

Comment: @latifmohammadkhan the code is not relevant here.

Comment: you should go for the sqlite database..make one sqlite database file and put it into assets folder and access it in your code..

Comment: @ambit hundreds is not that much, you can keep having it in an XML file, or store it in sqlite or SharedPreferences. If it becomes really big - then a DB will be the right choice.

Comment: efficient way depends on your requirements and how easy you feel to do that tedious work, use ArrayList or List rather than simple Arrays

Comment: Don't see any problem. What's difficult in managin string arrays?

Comment: i have uploaded some portions of code for those who need it. I cant use sqlite database because I need to hand over the source code to the client after I complete. He ll make changes to the string arrays and would launch 2-3 other apps like these. So, I want it to be the easiest for him to make changes as he is not a programmer. That is why I cant use databases

Comment: @Autocrab I don't think he meant how to manage string arrays. I think he wants a space efficient, high performance and easy to edit way to manage his contents shown in the list view.

Comment: Also the listview description sometimes contain multiple lines etc. So, I have to put a \n in between. All this might get difficult for the client to do. So far, string arrays looks to be the better solution. But if someone can suggest something better, it would be great

Comment: @ambit Alright if that is the case, I think using string array is already a desirable solution. Or you might want to define your own XML format that groups the heading and desc together.

Comment: @TwilightSun. Thanks but am not sure how do I define my own XML format  to group the heading and desc together. That sounds better than this. Please let me know about it

Comment: @ambit : **"...where even some non-programmer can replace the string array values for us. That is why we dont use sqlite."** - If you want a non-programmer to be able to edit / manage a data source then simply write a user-friendly, non-techie editing tool. If you're going to go to the trouble of writing an Android program, what difference does it make to write a data editing tool to go with it?

Comment: @ambit you mentioned that it is getting difficult to manage strings. You should mention which part is getting difficult. I also suggest writing a script that can convert a CSV or any format to the string array and modify your XML so client doesn't have to deal with the XML directly.

Comment: @Sundeep.. There are many strings. In addition, I need to take care of multiple lines and characters that are bold, underlined etc. Thanks for your suggestion for the script.

Comment: @Squonk. Thanks. Will see if I can do what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        HashMap<String, String> data1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
         data1.put("title","title string");
         data1.put("detail","detail paragraph");


        HashMap<String, String> data2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data1.put("title","title string");
         data1.put("detail","detail paragraph");


         myList.add(data1);
         myList.add(data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but my data was not static. It was being fetched from the web. I used JSON to handle that data.

I'm now sure how efficient or helpful it will be in your case.

Store data something like this:

```
JSONArray arrayOfJSONObjects = new JSONArray()
                .put(new JSONObject().put("title", "myTitle1").put("details", "myDetails1"))
                .put(new JSONObject().put("title", "myTitle2").put("details", "myDetails2"))
                .put(new JSONObject().put("title", "myTitle3").put("details", "myDetails3"));
```

To retrieve data use a simple for loop(this will we used in your adapter class):

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayOfJSONObjects.length();i++)
{
arrayOfJSONObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
arrayOfJSONObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("details");
}
```

Let me say again I'm not sure if this is efficient or helpful, but this is the most common practise while fetching data from URL.

Any non-programmer can copy paste or even edit the data. And u can put thousands of JSONObject, they will never ever slow u down.